# ¿Como soluciono el error Null check operator used on a null value en el Widget FadeInImage?

Tags: flutter, dart

les agradeceré muchísimo si me ayudan con este error que ya son 3 aplicaciones en las que me aparece, se trata del Null check operator used on a null value en el widget FadeInImage:

[image: Null check operator used on a null value]

el Error aparece cuando he cargado una imagen o varias en una pantalla y luego voy a otra por ejemplo a una pantalla de registrar nuevo producto y vuelvo a la pantalla donde estaban mis imagenes y aparece asi, con ese error... ya busqué arto en la red y no encuentro la solución...
aqui les de también los detalles del error en consola:

```
 ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
    The following _CastError was thrown building _AnimatedFadeOutFadeIn(duration: 1000ms, dirty, state: _AnimatedFadeOutFadeInState#1c03f(ticker inactive, targetOpacity: null, placeholderOpacity: null)):
    **Null check operator used on a null value**
    
    The relevant error-causing widget was: 
      FadeInImage FadeInImage:file:///C:/Users/HP/OneDrive/Escritorio/Flutter/productos_app/lib/widgets/product_card.dart:197:14
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
    #0      _AnimatedFadeOutFadeInState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/fade_in_image.dart:542:70)
```

y Aqui el codigo donde cargo las imagenes:

```
class _BackGroundImage extends StatelessWidget {

  final String? picture;
  const _BackGroundImage(this.picture);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /*return Card( //Manera 1 con Card
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)
        ),
        elevation: 7,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 50, left: 20, right: 20),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 400,
          child: const FadeInImage(
            placeholder: AssetImage('assets/jar-loading.gif'),
            image: AssetImage('assets/no-image.png'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )
        ),
      );*/
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 400,
        child: _getImageCard(picture)
      )
    );
  }

  Widget _getImageCard(String? picture) {
    if (picture == null) {
      return const Image(
          image: AssetImage('assets/no-image.png'), fit: BoxFit.cover);
    }
    if (picture.startsWith('http')) {
      return FadeInImage(
        placeholder: const AssetImage('assets/jar-loading.gif'),
        image: NetworkImage(picture),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      );
    }
    return Image.file(File(picture), fit: BoxFit.cover);
  }
```

Asi mismo les envio donde especificamente me marca el error del widget FadeInImage:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    ***//Aqui me marca el error, en el _placeholderOpacityAnimation.isCompleted***
                                                           |
                                                           V
    if (widget.wasSynchronouslyLoaded || _placeholderOpacityAnimation!.isCompleted) { 
      return widget.target;
    }

    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
      // Text direction is irrelevant here since we're using center alignment,
      // but it allows the Stack to avoid a call to Directionality.of()
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
```

Antes no exisitia ese error... pero al parecer por la actualización del sdk con null safety aparecio... Les ruego colegas si alguien ya tiene la solucion me pueda ayudar

Comment: Null safety apareció en Flutter 2 y vamos por flutter 3, deberías intentar usar siempre la última versión del framework. Supongo que en algún momento el _placeholder... Ese que tienes ahí en el código, es null y le estás diciendo al compilador que nunca lo será con `!`. Así que tendrás que probar que no sea null, antes de realizar alguna operación con esa variable.

Comment: Ya verifique bien y no hay un lugar donde le este mandando null, pues lo controlo muy bien antes de enviar los datos al Fade Imagen... este error se produce cuando voy de una pantalla a otra y la imagen ya estaba cargada y me aperece con ese error... al parecer es un problema con el puntero a memoria cache del placeholder como decia en una pagina que averigüe. decia el error pero no la solución...

Answer (score 0):

Me pasaba lo mismo, justo desarrollando una app similar. despues de tanto buscar encontré que con flutter 3.0.0 no sucede ese error. no me convencia la idea de volver de flutter 3.3.3 a 3.0.0 pero al menos me permitio continuar. no he visto mucha informacion al respecto. espero te sirva!

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Gracias Daniel, voy a probar y te aviso como me va...